# java - apache cxf client without wsdl

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf

I'm trying to send a really simple soap request using Apache CXF in Java: a message with only 1 element:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <element>some string</element>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The following tutorial describes usage of CXF for sending requests but it assumes that we have a WSDL file: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html

What should I do in case I don't have this WSDL? should I create one? how would it look like in this case?

edit: the service is not maintained by me.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial, you are looking is meant to produce a client. That means, your webservice will be existing or hosted on as server already. Your client will simply call it using this tutorial.

What you are looking for, CXF's JAX WS API implementation for your requirement. You can follow these basic tutorial to achieve that by simply using annotation and changing request and response message structue.

Tutorial links:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world

Comment: thanks for the answer. The service is not maintained by me (I dont even know if its a CXF service or something else). How can I get the wsdl file of it? (the way I reach the soap service by url:port; but url:port?wsdl doesn't show anything)

Comment: There is no other way, getting wsdl other than service provider.  if url?wsdl is not working,You can ask service provider for providing wsdl file.

Comment: is it possible to use CXF without the wsdl file?

Comment: The real question is, you want to be a service provider or service consumer. you can not consume service without having wsdl in webservice world. For the testing purpose,You can host a webservice locally, generate wsdl and consume that using a client if you want.